# Pandas Dataframe -update dynamic rows and columns without loops

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a source dataframe

```
source.head()
Out[41]: 
          A         B       C       compare
892  4.031250  6.218750  6.515625  4.246094
893  4.079531  6.222656  5.945312  4.038281
894  4.023438  6.226562  6.039062  4.250000
895  5.109531  4.238281  6.035156  4.038281
896  4.019531  6.242188  6.089844  4.242188
```

and a target dataframe with same index

```
target.tail()
Out[42]: 
          A    B    C
636893    0    0    0
636894    0    0    0
636895    0    0    0
636896    0    0    0
636897    0    0    0
```

I want to do this-

1. in source, select

   ```
    a. index where 'compare' is less than min of the rest. 
    b. the column of the min of the rest
   ```
2. in target, update that location (index and column) with source['compare']/source[min_col]

So with the above source values, the result of the target would be this

```
target.head()
Out[41]: 
           A                     B                     C
892        0                     0                     0
893        4.038281/4.079531     0                     0
894        0                     0                     0
895        0                     4.038281/4.238281     0
896        0                     0                     0
```

I do 1a. i.e. selecting index where compare less than min of the rest by:

```
      tenors = ['A', 'B', 'C']
      idx_select= source.index[(source['compare'] < source[tenors].min(1))]
```

I can do 1b. i.e. get the column where min occurs by:

```
      col_min = source.ix[idx_select, tenors].idxmin(1)
```

I am not sure how to the second step, i.e. update target values except doing a loop by rows.

Any suggestions to avoid loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following, hopefully it's self-explained:

```
cols = ['A','B','C']
target = df[cols].div(df.compare, axis='rows')
target = target.where(target.gt(1) & target.eq(target.min(1), axis='rows'), 0)
```

Output:

print(target)

```
            A         B    C
892  0.000000  0.000000  0.0
893  1.010215  0.000000  0.0
894  0.000000  0.000000  0.0
895  0.000000  1.049526  0.0
896  0.000000  0.000000  0.0
```